# Default argument not permitted in a tuple type when defining function type

Tags: swift

I’ve got a function like this:

```
func next(step: Int = 1){
    //....
}
```

And now I would like to define a type alias so that I can easily pass around this function.

However I am not able to find a way to declare that the first argument has a default value. I tried things like this

```
typealias ActionNext = (step: Int = default) -> ()

var nextFunc: ActionNext = next
```

but they all give me a error message like

> Default argument not permitted in a tuple type

Is there any way to define a type for this kind of function?

Answer (score 19):

**No**, that is not possible

Explanation:

> A *type alias declaration* introduces a named alias of an existing type into your program.

`(step: Int = 1) -> ()` is not a proper type. A type is for example `(step: Int) -> ()`, a default value is not allowed there.

If you write

```
typealias ActionNext = (Int) -> ()

var nextFunc: ActionNext = next
```

It works. Or even when you write `(step: Int) -> ()`

But I assume what you want to achieve is being able to call `nextFunc()` omitting the parameter and using its default value. That is not possible. To understand why, you can follow the [`Type Alias Declaration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/typealias-head) grammar - in the `type` you can not specify default values.

Comment: So basically your answer is "No"... Swift can be very disappointing.

Comment: @idmean yes, my answer is `No` :/ I will include that as the first statement ;)

Answer (score -3):

The problem is exactly what it says. You cannot provide a default argument in a type alias.

it must be like this:

```
 typealias ActionNext = (step: Int) -> ()
```

Your expectation to be able to set a default value is futile and doesn't make sense. (You showed disappointment with Swift in the comments, but fortunately Swift is doing just fine regarding this.)

First thing first, the action is a closure, which itself is also a type. 
A type itself CANNOT have some kind of value. Type is never a concrete value, it is a dimensionless trait of a variable, it's  qualitative description.

You need to properly understand the relationship between the three terms: 
Variable - type - value

A variable is an entity. It has three things - a name, a Type, and Value.

The value is a realisation of the type trait.

**EXAMPLE**

you could have a variable called *myDayOfRest* that would be of type `DayOfWeek` and can have values of `SU MO TU WE TH FR SA`.

Notice this -> let myDayOfRest be of type DayOfWeek and have a value of SA.

in Swift it would be

```
let myDayOfRest : DayOfWeek = SA
```

Now when you create a `type alias` for the DayOfWeek type.. basically you are just giving an alternative name to the TYPE. Never to the concrete variable. Always to the TYPE. But it's not the TYPE that has some value, it is variables who have values.

Hopefully now you can see why expecting to be able to provide a default value in a type alias does't make any sense.

Comment: I know the difference between variable, type and value pretty well. I don’t want to provide a value, I want to declare that there is a default value. That was just a guess how such a syntax might look like.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. AFAIK Swift doesn't have a concept of implicitly initialised variables. You have to take care of initialisation explicitly, which is an exceptionally good feature of the language imo.

Comment: You can declare default values for function arguments. (See the 1st code block in the question.) Swift has first-class function support. Therefore there should be a way to express in a function type that some arguments have a default value, right?

Comment: Just because a Named Closure/Global Function has a default argument value, it still doesn't mean the value is part of it's Type. 

The type of this :
 public func sum(a: Int = 0, b: Int) -> Int {
    
    return a + b
}

is (Int, Int) -> Int

not 
(Int = 0, Int) -> Int

Comment: Where did I state the value is part of the type? I just want to **point out** in the type that the function can take a default value. I don't care at all how such a type might look like. If `(a: Int¿)` declared that `a` **has** a default  value I would be completely satisfied. If that is not possible that’s a valid answer too of course.

Comment: 1) You stated it right in your typealias code. 2) Furthermore you don't need to "point out in the type that the function can take a default value". That is a language feature and it is present all the time. It would be pointless and redundant to point this out. It would serve no purpose. Actualy it would do some harm because you would loose visibility of the default value being present in some concrete function instance.

Comment: If it serves no point then please try to run `func next(step: Int = 1){}; let nextFunc = next; nextFunc();`. My question was just a guess how this syntax could look like. If you want to help me, that’s nice of you but you are just telling me what my intentions were and that’s not really helpful.

Comment: couldn't a type encode default value as a semantic of that type?  that doesn't seem entirely illogical to me.  just saying.