# Unexpected behaviour of default parameter in Swift

Tags: swift

If you have the following static method which has a parameter with default value:

```
struct Test {
  static func myFunction(_ name: String = "World") {
    print("Hello \(name)")
  }
}
```

you can call it without parameters:

```
Test.myFunction()
```

But if you assign this method to a constant, default value seems to be lost:

```
let myFunction = Test.myFunction
myFunction() // ERROR!
```

My questions are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. Can we somehow preserve default value for parameter when assigning to a variable/constant?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44828903/2976878. One solution in your case is just to do `let myFunction = { Test.myFunction() }`, or else add an additional overload, as shown in the linked Q&A.

Comment: Swift doesn't support default arguments on functions passed as value apparently. A slightly old question of mine related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479780/default-argument-not-permitted-in-a-tuple-type-when-defining-function-type

Comment: @Hamish if I overload method it will be ambiguous to assign this method to the variable.

Comment: @dimakura I would expect that (what if you want a reference to the method that takes a `String` parameter?). You can provide an explicit type annotation in order to disambiguate. Although interestingly enough, the compiler doesn't think that it's ambiguous w/o one, it prefers the `() -> Void` method (http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59fb83fb5806391a2a94c92f)

Comment: @Hamish This is because the first method has default value. If you remove default value from the first method, then `Test.myFunction` is ambitious. So it cannot contain both methods :((

Comment: @dimakura Okay, so if you don't want to have an overload with a default value, then you'll have to give `myFunction` an explicit type annotation. Although what's wrong with the code I showed?

Comment: @Hamish my problem is: https://github.com/dimakura/SSpec/issues/28. I want to avoid global functions and "hide" them inside a struct. I wanted a way for a user to define these functions globally, if they need to.

Comment: Assign methods to variables seemed a natural solution for this. But given Swift cannot preserve default values, it looks a bit verbose to me now.

Comment: @dimakura I might be missing something, but I still don't see what prevents you from using a method with default parameters values + an overload the excludes those parameters (for your specific use case: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59fb91f15806391a2a94c936)

Comment: @Hamish please check this code: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59fc05f68a4b1137fa18d737 to see the problem

Comment: @dimakura Ah, well what you’re asking for there simply isn’t possible; as said in the linked Q&A, closures don’t currently support default parameter values.

Comment: No prob. Thanks for your time @Hamish