# Swift How to use Default Parameter when assign function to a variable

Tags: swift

```
import Foundation

func test(_ a:Int,b:Int=10)->Int{
return a * b
}

print(test(2))
//20

//assign func test to a variable
var f = test

print(f(2))
//error: missing argument for parameter #2 in call
```

> How to use default params when assign a function to a variable ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34480109